# Full record url in nginx log

Tags: nginx

We use following nginx site configure file in our production env.

```
log_format main '$http_x_forwarded_for - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                '"$http_user_agent" $request_time';



server {
        root /srv/www/web;
        server_name *.test.com;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/xxx.test.com.access.log main;
```

Both "http://a.test.com/ping" and "http://b.test.com/ping" http request will be record in file xxx.test.com.access.log.

But there is a problem, nginx don't store "domain name" in xxx.test.com.access.log.

"http://a.test.com/ping" and "http://b.test.com/ping" share the same request "Get /ping".

How can I record "a.test.com" or "b.test.com" in nginx log?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Try adding the `$host` variable in log_format:

```
log_format main '$http_x_forwarded_for - $remote_user [$time_local] "$host" "$request" '
            '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
            '"$http_user_agent" $request_time';
```

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24host:

> $host
>
> This variable is equal to line Host in the header of request or name
>   of the server processing the request if the Host header is not
>   available.
>
> This variable may have a different value from $http_host in such
>   cases: 1) when the Host input header is absent or has an empty value,
>   $host equals to the value of server_name directive; 2) when the value
>   of Host contains port number, $host doesn't include that port number.
>   $host's value is always lowercase since 0.8.17.

Comment: We use "server_name *.test.com;" in nginx.conf, so "$host" is "*.test.com".

Comment: It works for me on Nginx 1.4.4. Have you "reload" nginx?

Comment: This is the predefined combined format (with $host added), for anyone who needs it; the questioner's example doesn't include `$remote_addr`, which many people will want for a standard user's IP address:  `log_format combined '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                    '"$host" "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                    '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';`    Source: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html

Comment: @TanHongTat only for the first request hostname is get logged and simultaneously requests won't be logged. Is there a way to log simultaneous requests too

Answer (score 76):

If you want to log the full requested url, then my method is

```
log_format main '$http_x_forwarded_for - $remote_user [$time_local] '
'"$request_method $scheme://$host$request_uri $server_protocol" '
'$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
'"$http_user_agent" $request_time';
```

So splitting the $request into its constituent parts and popping $host in the middle.   Also lets you see if the request is http or https.

Comment: This format has the advantage of being parseable by things that expect the standard format, like the filebeat nginx module and the grok patterns for logstash

Comment: Thanks. In my case, first field is better with `$remote_addr`

Comment: `$http_x_forwarded_for` helps you to capture client IP in multiple cases such as if the client is connecting directly as well as client is connecting via a proxy such as Cloudflare.